# Iterate calculation through a range of dates in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=f1930905dd00df724e992c2ea3a9493a)**

```
CREATE TABLE inventory (
    inbound_date DATE,
    product_name VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO inventory
(inbound_date, product_name)
VALUES 
("2020-01-25", "Product_A"),
("2020-02-18", "Product_B"),
("2020-03-14", "Product_C");
```

**Expected Result:**

```
query_dates     product_name    days_in_inventory
2020-04-01      Product_A             67
2020-04-01      Product_B             43 
2020-04-01      Product_C             18 

2020-04-02      Product_A             68
2020-04-02      Product_B             44
2020-04-02      Product_C             19 

2020-04-03      Product_A             69
2020-04-03      Product_B             45
2020-04-03      Product_C             20 

2020-04-04      Product_A             70
2020-04-04      Product_B             46
2020-04-04      Product_C             21
```

---

In the above table I have three different products with different `inbound_dates`. 
Now in the results I want to calculate the `days_in_inventory` for each product based on the difference between the variable `@query_dates` and `inbound_date`.

So far I am able to this for each date seperately with this query:

```
SET
@query_date = '2020-04-02';

SELECT
product_name,
@query_date,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, MAX(inbound_date), @query_date) AS days_in_inventory
FROM inventory
GROUP BY 1;
```

However, as you can see in the result I want to be able to query a **range of dates in one SQL statement** instead of doing it manually for each date.

---

What do I need to modify in the query so it iterates the calculation from `2020-04-01` until `2020-04-04` and gives me the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate the dates.  One simple method is a recursive CTE.  The rest is just `JOIN` and some date arithmetic:

```
with recursive dates as (
      select date('2020-04-01') as date 
      union all
      select date + interval 1 day
      from dates
      where date < '2020-04-04'
     )
SELECT product_name, d.date,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, i.inbound_date, d.date) AS days_in_inventory
FROM dates d CROSS JOIN
     inventory i
ORDER By d.date, i.product_name;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=f5c2e96772c7afc46d2f3a67ade9bbcf) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
             with recursive my_date as (
             select '2020-04-01' as query_date
             union all
             select date_add(query_date,interval 1 day) from my_date
             where query_date<'2020-04-04')
             SELECT
             product_name,
             query_date,
             TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, MAX(inbound_date), query_date) AS days_in_inventory
             FROM inventory cross join my_date 
             GROUP BY 1,2
             order by 2;
```

Have Used recursive cte to generate dates and passing each date as cross join to the inventory table